# ISupportIncrementalLoading retrieving exception

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile, uwp-xaml

I have implemented a `ISupportIncrementalLoading` interface to perform the incremental loading of a `ListView`.

The interface has the following code:

```
public interface IIncrementalSource<T>
    {
        Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetPagedItems(int pageIndex, int pageSize);
    }

    public class IncrementalLoadingCollection<T, I> : ObservableCollection<I>, 
        ISupportIncrementalLoading where T : IIncrementalSource<I>, new()
    {
        private T source;
        private int itemsPerPage;
        private bool hasMoreItems;
        private int currentPage;

        public IncrementalLoadingCollection(int itemsPerPage = 10)
        {
            this.source = new T();
            this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage;
            this.hasMoreItems = true;
        }

        public void UpdateItemsPerPage(int newItemsPerPage)
        {
            this.itemsPerPage = newItemsPerPage;
        }

        public bool HasMoreItems
        {
            get { return hasMoreItems; }
        }

        public IAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult> LoadMoreItemsAsync(uint count)
        {

            return Task.Run<LoadMoreItemsResult>(
                async () =>
                {
                    uint resultCount = 0;
                    var dispatcher = Window.Current.Dispatcher;
                    var result = await source.GetPagedItems(currentPage++, itemsPerPage);

                    if(result == null || result.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        hasMoreItems = false;
                    } else
                    {
                        resultCount = (uint)result.Count();
                        await Task.WhenAll(Task.Delay(10), dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                        {
                            foreach (I item in result)
                                this.Add(item);
                        }).AsTask());
                    }



                    return new LoadMoreItemsResult() { Count = resultCount };

                }).AsAsyncOperation<LoadMoreItemsResult>();
        }
    }
```

The instance of the interface is this one:

```
var collection = new IncrementalLoadingCollection<LiveTextCode, LiveText>();
this.LTextLW.ItemsSource = collection;
```

Where `LiveText` is a `UserForm` and `LiveTextCode` is a class that, among other functionalities, sets the previous `UserForm` up.

The `UserForm` is filled by reading XML files located in a server so the code must perform `async` operations and, for that, the containing scope has to be also. Due to an unknown reason, the instance of the custom interface is called before it's filling so, I'm getting a `NullReferenceException` (or at least that the hypothesis that makes most sense to me...).

I'm pretty lost and I don't know how to fix it, if anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: May I recommend this sample? https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/tree/master/Samples/IncrementalLoading/IncrementalLoading

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `this.LTextLW.ItemsSource = collection;`
Specify an ObservableCollection item say `collection`. Now bind this to your listview by binding it to your `ItemsSource="{Binding collection}"`.
Since its an ObservableCollection type as soon as your collection value gets updated it will be reflected in your View also.
Else you can also specify a collection with a `RaisePropertyChanged` Event

```
private IncrementalLoadingCollection<LiveTextCode, LiveText> _collection;
public IncrementalLoadingCollection<LiveTextCode, LiveText> collection
        {
            get { return _collection; }
            set
            {
                _collection = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
```

This will handle updation of UI whenever the value changes.